# Index rebuild for partitioned tables?

Tags: oracle, partitioning

Friends...I'm trying to debug procedure to move and rebuild indexes for partitioned tables.

I'm trying to do below:

1. Move partitioned table to new tablespace
2. Rebuild indexes of #1 partitioned tables

For #2 I'm using dba_ind_partitions but since it doesn't have table_name, table_owner it's hard to filter out.

```
PROCEDURE moveParTbl (OldTbs in varchar2, NewTbs in varchar2)
    AUTHID CURRENT USER
IS
  CURSOR curTable IS
    SELECT table_owner, table_name, partition_name, tablespace_name
      FROM dba_tab_partition
      WHERE tablespace_name = OldTbs
      ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;

  CURSOR curIndex (lParNam IN varchar2)
IS
  SELECT index_owner, index_name, partition_name, tablespace_name
  FROM dba_ind_partitions
  WHERE partition_name = lParNam;


BEGIN
  FOR rec1 IN curTable LOOP

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table ' || rec1.table_owner || '.' || rec1.table_name ||
                      ' move partition ' || rec1.partition_name || ' tablespace ' ||NewTbs;

   -- Starting curIndex
  FOR rec2 IN curIndex (rec1.partition_name) LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'rebuild index ' || rec2.index_owner || '.' || rec2.index_name ||
                      ' rebuild partition ' || rec2.partition_name || ' tablespace ' ||NewTbs || ' online';

      END LOOP; -- index cursor loop
      END LOOP;  --curTable for loop
END moveParTbl;
```

What's the error:

```
1 Table: Tab-A, Tab-B, Tab-C
2. Index: Tab-A (Ind1, Ind2, Ind3)
```

Tab-A 3 indexes gets rebuild after every partitioned table move and not just once after Tab-A move.

*** below is wrong

```
Move Tab-A
Rebuild ind1, ind2, ind3
Move TAb-B
Rebuild ind1, ind2, ind3
Move Tab-C
Rebuld ind1, ind2, ind3
```

*** How it should be

```
Move Tab-A
Rebuild ind1, ind2, ind3
Move TAb-B
Move Tab-C
```

Comment: You are rebuilding each index partition once you've moved the table partition. That seems correct to me. Is it someway rebuilding the same index partition more than once?

Comment: @DanielStolf, Problem is with the logic how partition_name gets feeds into curIndex. I'm trying to avoid rebuilding of same partition_name index after every table move and limit to only rebuilding index of (table_name, table_owner, partition_name).

Comment: So are you just asking how to identify the partitions for indexes related to a particular table - you want to know how to join `dba_ind_partitions` to another view that does have the table?

Comment: @AlexPoole, I'm just trying to rebuild indexes of the partitioned tables which were move by curTable cursor. Since I can't pass table_owner and table_name to dba_ind_partition it's get bit complicated.

Comment: you need to join dba_tables, dba_indexes and dba_ind_partitions. try something like this:
  CURSOR curIndex (lTabNam IN varchar2, lParNam IN varchar2)
IS
    select i.index_name, ip.partition_name from 
        dba_tables t join dba_indexes i 
    on t.table_name=i.table_name 
        join dba_ind_partitions ip on i.index_name=ip.index_name
    where t.table_name=lTabNam and ip.partition_name=lParNam;

Comment: BTW, I would rebuild the index partitions all at once after moving the table partitions... but that's your call, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have repeated partition names across your tables (oracle doesn't complain about that because the full segment_name is composed of `[object_name]_[partition_name]`). You need to join `dba_tables` and `dba_indexes` (on `table_name` and `table_owner`) and `dba_ind_partitions` (on `index_name` and `index_owner`) if you want to get only indexes partitions related to that specific table partition. Your cursor `curIndex` should look like this:

```
          CURSOR curIndex (lTabOwn IN varchar2, lTabNam IN varchar2, lParNam IN varchar2)
          IS
            select i.index_owner, i.index_name, ip.partition_name from 
                dba_tables t join dba_indexes i 
            on t.table_name=i.table_name and t.owner=i.table_owner
                join dba_ind_partitions ip on i.index_name=ip.index_name and 
                     i.owner=ip.index_owner
            where t.table_name=lTabNam and ip.partition_name=lParNam and 
            and t.owner=lTabOwn and status<>'USABLE';
```

And, of course, you'll need to feed owner and table_name into it also, not only the partition_name.

Comment: that does the trick... this was indeed some tricky joins required. I feeded table_owner, table_name and partition_name and looks like it's good... need to test thoroughly...